# Streamlining deployment with Capistrano

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano

Is there any way I can streamline my deployment process?  I currently use these git and Capistrano commands:

```
git add .
git commit -am 'Comment...'
git push [name]

cap deploy:setup
cap deploy
cap deploy:cleanup
```

So if I want to make minor changes, I have to enter my password four times (once for push, once for setup, and twice for deploy).  Is there any way I can reduce the amount of commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your git workflow is pretty standard, and you're not going to streamline it much. You don't need to push every commit, I suppose, and there's nothing wrong with a lot of small, atomic commits.

As far as `cap deploy` goes, though, why are you running the setup and cleanup every time? Can't you just run `cap deploy`? If you need to run `cleanup` every time, try redefining `deploy`'s default to include it. In your `deploy.rb`:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc <<-DESC
    Deploys your project. This calls both `update' and `restart'. Note that \
    this will generally only work for applications that have already been deployed \
    once. For a "cold" deploy, you'll want to take a look at the `deploy:cold' \
    task, which handles the cold start specifically.
  DESC
  task :default do
    update
    restart
    cleanup # <-- this is added
  end
end
```

If you have a good reason to run `setup` every time, you can add that to the redefined default task as well.